# "OpenSSL: NOT OK" after roundcube installation

Tags: php, windows, wamp, roundcube, php-openssl

I am trying to install roundcube on localhost and I am getting the error

```
OpenSSL:  NOT OK
```

The `php.ini` has "extension=php_openssl.dll" enabled without the ";"

what could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: have you checked the logs? is the certificate valid?

Comment: There is no certificate.  How can i disable this to install roundcube

Comment: about that i can't tell you any more than the manual. except that you *should* use SSL, though.

Comment: Are you using WAMPServer and if so which version?

Comment: @RiggsFolly 3.0.6 on win 10

Comment: Did that help any?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that php_openssl is enabled within the Apache-PHP environment.

There are 2 php.ini files in WAMPServer for each version of PHP you have installed.

To make sure you are editing the one that controls the Apache-PHP environment use the wampmanager menus.

Either:

```
(left click) wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

and edit the php.ini file that is loaded into your editor directly

Or using the menus again, you can turn PHP extensions on and off directly from the menu and this will guarantee you are editing the correct php.ini file

[image]

[image]

Now all you do is click the extension name. If it is ticked it is already activated. 
When you click the line for an extension, it will activate the extension or  deactivate it i.e. toggle its active state

Oh the `php.ini` file you find in `wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini` effects only the PHP CLI i.e. PHP when run from the command line. So if you are using anything like composer which uses a lot of command line tools, you would make sure that the extensions you wanted to use were activated in this version of the `php.ini`

Comment: I dont have such menus but the openssl is enabled in both the php.ini list manually.

Comment: You do have these menus. Look in the System Tray expansion area for the Green W icon. Thats Wampmanager

Comment: I right click on the wamp menu and i get tools / wamp settings / language / about / help / refersh and exit.  none these pope up as you mentioned.  I am using 3.0.6, 32 bit.

Comment: Note the instruction in the answer **(left click)** then you will see these menus